# Using multiple links style on the same label

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use different links style on the same label using TTTAtributedLabel?

For example for: "one two" I do want "one" to be link with underline and blue color and "two" to be a link with color green and no underline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the attributes for text at the ranges of those links.